# Adding numbers with Javascript 

Tags: javascript

Easy question:
I'm trying to add a number to an array like this:

```
sorted[4][2]+=nbrMvt[i];
```

but it adds the two numbers as if they were strings. The output just puts the numbers one beside the other...
I have tried these methods:

```
sorted[4][2]+=parseInt(nbrMvt[i]);

sorted[4][2]=sorted[4][2]+nbrMvt[i];

sorted[4][2]=parseInt(sorted[4][2])+parseInt(nbrMvt[i]);
```

But none of them work.

[EDIT]

Ok, here is how I created my array:

```
var sorted = MultiDimensionalArray(13,4);
```

I then atribute string values to the sorted[x][0...12]
the last example gives me "NaNNaNNaNNaN"

```
 function MultiDimensionalArray(iRows,iCols)
  {
  var i;
  var j;
     var a = new Array(iRows);
     for (i=0; i < iRows; i++)
     {
         a[i] = new Array(iCols);
         for (j=0; j < iCols; j++)
         {
             a[i][j] = "";
         }
     }
     return(a);
  }
```

(btw, what should I understand from the vote down on my question?)

Comment: Did you by any chance define the numbers in the array as "1" ?

Comment: Lets have a little more context about how you are creating/filling your `sorted` variable. More than likely it's values are strings, causing the `+=` to be concatenation.

Comment: Could you also provide some example output for your question. You will need to define your question a little more for people to give you a good answer.

Comment: @Chad: that wouldn't explain why the last example isn't working, though, would it?

Comment: @DavidHedlund No, but there is no way for us to test, confirm, and/or propose a new solution without more context of what is going on in his code.

Comment: @Chad: agreed. Off the top of my head, I can't think of *anything* that would explain why the last one wouldn't be working.

Comment: What the hell is `MultiDimensionalArray(13,4)`. Are you using a framework?

Comment: A down vote means the community does not think your question is clear and shows a good amount of effort. Here are the [conditions of a down vote](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down). Try improving the focus of your question and looking to the suggestions in the comments.

Comment: Chad you found my problem: "What the hell is MultiDimensionalArray(13,4)" I wrote a function that created the array and defined everything as a string. You can write an answer if you want me to mark it as my chosen answer...

Comment: If you want to call out to someone who previously spoke in the comments you just mention their username like this: @sebastienleblanc .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `MultiDimensionalArray(iRows,iCols)` function is defining the array contents as strings. When you try to add a number to an element in the array like: `sorted[4][2] += 2` it is just concatenating to that string.

However the following should still work, even in that instance:

```
sorted[4][2] = parseInt(sorted[4][2])+parseInt(nbrMvt[i]);
```

**Unless** `nbrMvt[i]` is in an invalid format, causing `parseInt()` to return `NaN`. Which would make the sum also `NaN`.

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vPcqm/2/) of working code similar to yours, with a small rewrite to your `MultiDimensionalArray()` function.

Comment: I get that it should still work, but it doesn't... I fixed it by changing the line `a[i][j] = "";` by  `a[i][j] = 0;` in my `MultiDimensionalArray` function. Thank you :)

Comment: `parseInt("")` is `NaN`. So your initial value breaks the sum of those two numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You may not have set some value (perhaps i === null or somthing) ... But this works:

```
var sorted = [], 
nbrMvt = [],
i = 0;
// set up arrays and populate just enough values...
nbrMvt[i] = 40;
sorted[4] = [];
sorted[4][2] = 2;

sorted[4][2]=parseInt(sorted[4][2])+parseInt(nbrMvt[i]);

document.write(sorted[4][2]);
```

Comment: Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vPcqm/1/) of his code working as expected (with assumptions). Without more context a clear answer can't really be developed.

Answer (score 0):

If you `x+=4` you get `NaN` in `x` if it was `null` or `undefined` before.

It is good to fill thing you will `+=` with *number* `0` first.

If you `x+=4` you get `"104"` in `x` if it was *string* `"10"` before, not a *number* 10.
If you `x+=y` you get `"104"` in `x` even if `x` was previously number `10` but y is *string* `"4"`.

It is good to explicitly cast to number (using `+foo`; that is unary plus, not the addition operator, the shortest way to force number coercion in Javascript) if you want to have number arithmetics.